# How to access Stripe webhooks when using Vercel + Supabase (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, vercel, supabase

I've been going around in circles for a bit with this - I'll try keep it concise.

I have a React JS app, and have integrated with Stripe for the billing. I have a freemium version, but if someone wants to go to the paid plan they can upgrade in app > they're redirected to stripe's checkout. I pass through the instance ID, and then use that to update my database in Supabase to update their plan data, so I can update their feature visibility.

It's working locally when I run my server, however I'm deployed with vercel and it doesn't host the server. So I've created an api/stripe-webhook file and added the following code. However it doesn't work, and in Stripe's dashboard I can see I'm getting a HTTP status code 405 (Method Not Allowed) response.

```
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js')
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.VITE_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_TEST)
const supabaseUrl = process.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.VITE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
const service_role_key = process.env.VITE_SUPABASE_SERVICE_KEY

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)

const supabaseAdmin = createClient(supabaseUrl, service_role_key, {
  auth: {
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    supabaseClient: supabase,
  },
})
const signingSecretTest = process.env.VITE_STRIPE_WEBHOOK_TEST

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rawBody = req.body.toString('utf8')
    const sigHeader = req.headers['stripe-signature']
    const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      rawBody,
      sigHeader,
      signingSecretTest,
    )
    if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
      const session = event.data.object
      console.log(session)
      if (session?.payment_status === 'paid' && session?.client_reference_id) {
        const updateData = {
          last_payment_amount: session?.amount_total,
          last_payment_date: session?.created,
          plan_status: 'active',
          instance_id: session?.client_reference_id,
          plan_name: 'standard',
          price_per_seat:15
        }

        const { error } = await supabaseAdmin
          .from('settings')
          .update(updateData)
          .eq('instance_id', session?.client_reference_id)

        if (error) {
          console.error('Error updating settings:', error)
        }
      }
    }

    return new Response('Webhook received successfully', {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Webhook error:', err)
    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
  }
}
```

Things I’ve tried/done:

- Put the stripe-webhook.js file in a very specific location (/api/stripe-webhook.js)
- Added info to my vercel config file that tells it where to look.
- Checked all the environment variables are in Vercel
- Checked all the enviroment variables are correct and that I’m accessing the test mode versions.
- Checked it does work in local mode - it does (haven't included my server.js code but can add if needed).
- Used postman to check if i got the same error - i did. Still 405 method not allowed.
- Duplicated the settings table in Supabase and made the new one public, in case it was related to Row level security. No change, reverted.

My vercel.json:

```
{
  "routes": [
    { 
      "src": "/[^.]+", 
      "dest": "/", 
      "status": 200 
    },
    { 
      "src": "/api/stripe-webhook", 
      "methods": ["POST", "OPTIONS"], 
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
      }, 
      "dest": "/api/stripe-webhook.js" 
    }
  ]
}
```

My vite.config:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
export default defineConfig({
  define: {
    'process.env.VITE_STRIPE_API_KEY_PUBLISHABLE_TEST': JSON.stringify(
      process.env.VITE_STRIPE_API_KEY_PUBLISHABLE_TEST,
    ),
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/',
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },

  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'assets',
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: my url,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '/api/stripe-webhook'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I'm super stuck and would appreciate any insight.